# Elastic Beanstalk, Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried Elastic Beanstalk for rails. When I run eb deploy I got this error. I need to install at least bundler 1.8.4. Any idea how to resolve this?

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
    In Gemfile:
      bundler (>= 1.8.4) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
     bundler (1.7.3)

 This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
 Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`? (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Comment: @pangpang still the same after I run bundle install and run eb deploy the same error.

Comment: you can run `gem uninstall bundler -v 1.7.3`, then run `gem install bundler ` to install the latest version.

Comment: if also doesn't work, please provide the error info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am upgrading the pre-installed bundler by adding an elastic beanstalk config file to my  project. I am running an older version of Elastic beanstalk box, so feel free to change the ruby paths to fit your box.

file name:
`.ebextensions/upgrade_bundler.config`

file content:

```
commands:
  update_bundler:
    command: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/gem install bundler -v 1.8.4
```

Comment: check if you can use the path: `/opt/rubies/ruby-current/bin/gem` worked for me.