# Why does Elastic Beanstalk keep asking me to change from a root user for Bundler in a Rails app after I've changed it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, bundler, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails app online using Elastic Beanstalk from AWS as part of a project. I'm using the AWS and EB CLI and I can run `eb init` without a problem. However, when I try to run `eb create myproject-env` it leads to this warning:

> {DATE}    ERROR   [Instance: myInstance] Command failed on instance. Return code: 20 Output: (TRUNCATED)...dor/cache ']'
>   + bundle install
>   Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
>   installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
>   users on this machine.
>   You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
>   Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

I've tried googling the problem and I keep being lead back to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437817/dont-run-bundler-as-root-what-is-the-exact-difference-made-by-using-root), which makes sense as far as I can tell. The thing is, I can't figure out how to get past this error. I've tried making new IAM users and using `--profile myProfile`, I've changed the user in Command Prompt, and I've uninstalled and reinstalled Bundler, awscli, and awsebcli. I'd like to keep this in the CLI just because I want to be able to use `eb deploy` in the future. And I can run the app locally using Puma with no problem, so I feel like I just haven't configured something correctly with AWS.

I also can't figure out the error about using a version of Bundler 2 or higher, because I am using a higher version on my computer right now.

I'm using Rails 5.2.2, Ruby 2.4.4, and Bundler 2.0.1 and I'm using Windows Command Prompt.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to tell Elastic Beanstalk the version of `bundler` you want. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240973/elastic-beanstalk-bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler#answer-30243577) out. The answer is a little old, so ensure you specify the right version of `bundler` to install.

Comment: I did something similar to this based on another answer, actually, but I ultimately had to install Ubuntu because Command Terminal kept treating me as the root user. Thank you so much for your response, though!